# jQuery select all emails from text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, textarea

I am trying to select dynamically all valid emails which are entered into a text area and spaced by either a space or a comma. (I'm not sure how to use a regex to achieve this in javascript).

My main issue is a number of false positives and extra duplicate information is being displayed, (I assume from using keyup), is there a way to fix this problem so it only shows each valid email once?

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('.emails').keyup(function () {
    var matches = $('.emails').val().split(' ');
    for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++){
        if (validEmail(matches[i])){
            $('#emails-send').append("<div class='newmail'>" + matches[i] + "</div>");
        }
    }
});

function validEmail(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};

});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352221/jquery-validation-plugin-multiple-email-addresses

Comment: maybe use "parse" instead of "select" in the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the results in another object and check if they're already appended like this: http://jsfiddle.net/LKPwg/2/

this also uses a timeout to prevent incomplete emails addresses to be added.

```
var results = {};
var timer = null;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.emails').keyup(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout("parseEmails()", 500);
    });
});

function parseEmails() {
    var matches = $('.emails').val().split(' ');
    for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
        if (validEmail(matches[i])) {
            if (results[matches[i]] == undefined) {
                results[matches[i]] = matches[i];
                $('#emails-send').append("<div class='newmail'>" + matches[i] + "</div>");
            }

        }
    }
}

function validEmail(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};​
```

as for the comma/whitespace seperation, you could replace comma with whitespace first:

```
$('.emails').val().replace(',', ' ').split(' ')
```

**UPDATE**

http://jsfiddle.net/LKPwg/4/

alternate way of checking for duplicates, by searching for a substring of the found token in the results and just updating the result-div in that case: 
(this example doesn't need the timeout and uses the data-attribute to identify results)

```
var substr = matches[i].substr(0, (matches[i].length - 1));
if (results[substr]) {
  delete results[substr];
  $('#emails-send .newmail[data-email="' + substr + '"]').html(matches[i]).attr('data-email', matches[i]);
}
else {
  $('#emails-send').append("<div class='newmail' data-email=" + matches[i] + ">" + matches[i] + "</div>");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, mapping known emails to the results is a good way to avoid duplicates. Can you think of a better way than a timer to wait for a compelte email? I could check for a space or comma after each email then add it, but that doesn't work for the single case..