# Plugin for entering multiple unknown email addresses

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, input

I need an email form where users can add multiple receiver email addresses. The textbox should be validated to a csv (, or ; or whatever) of email addresses AND most importantly the addresses should become a little separated and visually more attractive while entering. (e.g. like the tags input field on stackoverflow)

Is there a Javascript Library / jQuery Plugin for that?

Or in other words (and especially if there's no plug'n'play Solution):
Which possible way of realizing this do you think will create the best and most easy to understand User Experience?

Notice:
- Autocompletion won't work here since the user can enter whatever email address he wants.
- pure validation is already out there, but it doesn't help the input field look more visually attractive to the user when there's a large csv...
Here are some validation examples:
[jQuery validation plugin multiple email addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352221/jquery-validation-plugin-multiple-email-addresses)
or https://gist.github.com/1118247

Comment: Research, research, research.

Comment: I searched a while but i couldn't find anything more than just autocompletion or validation. If you found one you were luckier than me, could you please post a link @Beetroot-Beetroot?

Comment: What I'm saying is the StackExchange is a questions and answers service, not a research service.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot What are you trying to do, scare him away? Besides, finding the right library for a task is obviously part and parcel of what StackExchange is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like selectize.js has most of the features you're looking for:

http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/