# Detect when text is entered into the textarea and change it correspondingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have a `textarea` where users can enter or paste email addresses of other people and send them an invite after pressing Submit button. Each email must be seperated with a comma and valid before the form is submitted - validation is taken care of by [jQuery Validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) & [multiemail method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352221/jquery-validation-plugin-multiple-email-addresses).

**Problem**

Some people paste email addresses directly from their email clients and those emails are often in a weird format - containing name and surname before the actual email, or the email is wrapped in < >. For example:
`"The Dude" <the.dude@gmail.com>, "The Dudette" <thedudette193@gmail.com>`

**Question**

What I want to do is to [Extract all email addresses from bulk text using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440444/extract-all-email-addresses-from-bulk-text-using-jquery), but I'm having problems integrating this piece of code to work with my `textarea` - I don't know where to start.

How could I use the code from the above answer to extract each email entered into the `textarea` after a comma is typed or when the focus is moved away from `textarea`? So if I paste `"The Dude" <the.dude@gmail.com>` and type `,` after it or switch focus away, the entered value would change to `the.dude@gmail.com`.

Comment: similar question check here for answers

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440444/extract-all-email-addresses-from-bulk-text-using-jquery

Comment: he is referencing to the same question. In fact his question must be "how to bind an event handler to a textarea"

Comment: reconsider validation after a comma.. you don't press comma key after the last email.. don't you want to validate it for example 2 seconds after a change was made?

Comment: @Dropout yes, that's why I also need the when-focus-is-moved-elsewhere validation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing something like this :

```
var textarea = $('#emails');

textarea.on({
    keyup: function(e) {
        if (e.which === 188) check();
    },
    blur: check    
});

function check() {
    var val  = $.trim(textarea.val()),
        err  = '';

    if (!val.length) {
        err = 'No input ?';
        return;
    }

    var emails   = val.split(','),
        notvalid = [],
        temp     = [];

    $.each(emails, function(_,mail) {
        mail = $.trim(mail);
        if ( mail.length ) {
            var m = mail.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
            if (m) {
                temp.push(m);
            }else{
                temp.push(mail);
                notvalid.push(mail)
            }
        }else{
            temp.push(mail);
        }
        if (notvalid.length) err = 'Not valid emails : ' + notvalid.join(', ');
    });

    $('#error').html(err);
    textarea.val((temp.length ? temp : emails).join(', '));
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/242hY/)

Answer (score 3):

you can detect when an textarea is changed (or other input field) by using an eventhandler. Jquery supports multiple events (have a look here http://api.jquery.com/category/events/). In this particular case I should use the keyup event for triggering the extractEmails function. This way your extraction will be "live". However, it is also possible by catching a blur or change event.

> With keyup eventhandler
>
> http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/9hLtW/5/

```
$('#text').on('keyup',function(event) {
    emails=extractEmails($(this).val());
    $("#emails").text(emails);
});

function extractEmails (text)
{
    return text.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will convert the entered text to emails when you either lose focus, or enter a comma, as you requested:

```
function extractEmails (text)
{
    return text.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
}

$("#emailtext").on('keypress blur', function(e) {

    if (e.which === 44 || e.type =="blur")
    {
        $('#emails').text(extractEmails($("#emailtext").val()));
    }
});
```

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mj2KM/