# jQuery Validate does wrong thing with type="email" and multiple

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

We are updating our forms to use the correct html 5 input types.  Our entry field has the following:

```
<input name="AlternateEmailAddress" class="validation-error" id="AlternateEmailAddress" aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="AlternateEmailAddress-error" type="email" value="" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" multiple>
```

We are also using jQuery Validate, version v1.15.1 because we need to support older browsers, and have a custom plugin for handling multiple email addresses. The rules setup are as follows

```
AlternateEmailAddress: {
    multipleemail:true,
    maxlength:1000,
    asciionly:true
}
```

multipleemail and asciionly are our custom values. multipleemail is similar to [jQuery validation plugin multiple email addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352221/jquery-validation-plugin-multiple-email-addresses).

For some reason, though, jQuery Validate does the single email validation, even though we have it turned off.  It is using their default text, not the text that we are specifying.

Is there a way to turn type="email" validation off, or is there a fix for when we use the multiple attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to turn `type="email"` validation off, or is there a fix for when we use the multiple attribute?

The simple fact that you have a `type="email"` attribute automatically triggers the `email` validation rule in jQuery Validate.

You can disable it by defining this rule as `false` in the `.validate()` method.

```
....
AlternateEmailAddress: {
    email: false,         // <- disable email rule
    multipleemail: true,
    maxlength: 1000,
    asciionly: true
    ...
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/196bdo8g/](https://jsfiddle.net/196bdo8g/)**